# Should we migrate 3 TB On Premise File Server to the Cloud?

Tags: document-library, document

We have a 3 TB File Server which we are planning to migrate to the Sharepoint Cloud in 13 different Document Libraries. 
Of the 3 TB Data:
50% files are Photoshop and Coreldraw.
The rest 50% is Word, Excel, PPT, PDF & Picture files.

Post implementation - My data is going to be shared between 50 users in my office using OneDrive Sync client.

Should I consider moving ahead or not?
Any tools recommended for this migrations.

Thanks,
Nikunj Dalal

Answer (score 1):

3TB on the OneDrive sync client isn't going to work. For Photoshop I'd look into Adobe's cloud services, not sure about Coreldraw. The sync client also runs into performance issues at roughly 300K files synchronized, though can have performance issues with >100k.

Office-related documents, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar situation recently.  If you can coach the client away from the sync requirement to a local machine, this will be no problem - SP and ODFB can handle any file type you throw at them.  It's a cultural shift that can be managed with a philosophical understanding of what the cloud is there to do for users; but if they still want to access everything through file explorer via ODFB sync, then as @Trevor mentioned, this will now work.  ODFB sync has been undergoing improvements, but it still can't sync that level of volume.  Teach the users how to find and use the data in SharePoint.  Turn on files on demand by default - always available on the cloud.  Plan and use robust metadata if you're only planning to use 3 document libraries to ensure logical and manageable grouping/finding of content. There is a native SP migration tool but it needed improvement last time I've used it; a third party tool like Sharegate is a good idea for the inventory and analysis you'll need to do.